Polars: How to prevent: polars.exceptions.InvalidOperationError: `min` operation not supported for dtype `null`
Hi I have the following data frame with only one row, that can contain an empty list (with only one value null).
When I try to get the min over the list, and the one row dataframe does contain only an empty list I run in the following error
polars.exceptions.InvalidOperationError: `min` operation not supported for dtype `null`

MRE
import polars as pl

data = pl.DataFrame({"list_col": [[None]]}, schema={"list_col": pl.List})
print(data)
col = "list_col"
data.with_columns(pl.col(col).list.min().alias(col + "_min"))

shape: (1, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ list_col   │
│ ---        │
│ list[null] │
╞════════════╡
│ [null]     │
└────────────┘

What I've tried
With a conditional pl.when()
data.with_columns(
                pl.when(pl.col(col).is_not_null()).then(pl.col(col).list.min()).alias(col + "_min")).collect()

Additionally before drop nulls from the list
data.with_columns(
                pl.when(pl.col(col).list.drop_nulls().is_not_null()).then(pl.col(col).list.min()).alias(col + "_min")).collect()

Solution
Thanks to the help of jqurious I was able to solve it. It is pretty simple, you just need to ensure that the dtype of the inner list is properly set, e.g., rather than pl.List(pl.Null) set it to the appropriate dtype e.g. pl.List(pl.Float)
# Solution convert the dtype
data = data.with_columns(pl.col(col).cast(pl.List(pl.Float64)))
data
# Now works as expected
data.with_columns( pl.col(col).list.min().alias(col + "_min").alias(col))


Can you pass the inner type of the list to the schema? e.g. pl.List(pl.String) or whatever.

Appreciate it, that solved it. Added an update edit to make it more visible
